# how to convert nicely from an IEnumerable<T> to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `IEnumerable<Int32>` and I want to convert it to a `List<Int32>`.
What's the nicest way to do it? (without iterating through the IEnumerable)

Comment: Either way you look at it, you have to enumerate and enumerable to get items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, or the [`List<T>` constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = ...;
List<int> numberList = numbers.ToList();
List<int> numberList2 = new List<int>(numbers);
```

Regardless, as others have said, you'll have to enumerate the original `Enumerable<int>`, (whether you do it manually or not) though, it's possible that one or both of those methods will be able to operate more efficiently than a naïve enumeration if the original `IEnumerable` is a `List<T>` or `ICollection<T>`.

Also, if you have a non-generic `IEnumerable`, you'll need to convert it to an `IEnumerable<T>` first before you can use either of these approached, using the [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method on `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 12):

Sure you can call a **ToList()** method on it

Answer (score 8):

An IEnumerable *always* has to be iterated to produce a list.  Yes, you can avoid writing the code by using IEnumerable<>.ToList() extension method.  It is still O(n).

Comment: Doesn't `ToList()` always create a new list? Returning the existing list could cause surprises.

Comment: @Jon: Actually, it's still iterated and still O(n).

Comment: @Stephen: Not if you cast it. I was responding to the first sentence: you can "produce" a `List<T>` just by casting the `IEnumerable<T>` if it's already a `List<T>`. I'm not suggesting it's a good idea, but it's worth mentioning :) (The equivalent for `ReadOnlyList<T>` *is* a good idea though.)

Comment: I thought `ToList()` performed a `CopyTo` if the target enumerable is an `ICollection<T>`, and enumerates if it is anything else? Therefore, wouldn't `ToList` on an enumerable that is a `IList<T>` would also perform a `CopyTo` of the underlying array?

Comment: @Jon: OK, I misunderstood you (I thought you were referring to `ToList`, instead of casting).

Comment: @Matthew: It does. But `CopyTo` enumerates the collection. It just does it in a more efficient way (O(n) instead of O(n*log(n)) if my rusty analysis skills are still operating correctly).

Comment: @Stephen: They're both sort-of O(n), but if the source sequence is an `ICollection<T>` then it's straight O(n). If not then it's amortised O(n) as the list's underlying array is auto-expanded as elements are added, which I suppose might end up as something like O(n log n) if you're unlucky.

Answer (score 2):

```
new List(enumerable);
```

Using the [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

Of course, this iterates through all elements in the background, but its not possible without anyway for two reasons:

1. `List<T>` is not a wrapper of another list but the implementation of dynamically sized arrays.
2. `List<T>` provides methods and properties that `IEnumerable<T>` has not (like `Count`), and which cannot be determined without iterating through all elements.